# Get source table name for slicers

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I want to find the source table and column name for slicer in excel 2013. I found out that:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Measure_1").SourceName
```

will yield the result in VBA, but I am not able to capture it.
 Can someone please give a sample code for this?

Answer (score 2):

Slicers are linked to PivotTables and PivotTables are linked to the source table.
So access first the PivotTable and then the table. Something like.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Measure_1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").SourceData
```

Or if you don't know which PivotTable(s) is/are linked to it, you can use a loop.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Measure_1").PivotTables
    Debug.Print pt.Name, pt.SourceData
Next
```

This will give you the PivotTable associated with your Slicer and the corresponding Table source. HTH.

Comment: Thanks L42, actually I am very poor in excel programming. Can you give me some link where I can go step by step in executing above code.

Comment: @VaibhavDhore You can start in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820991(v=office.15).aspx). Btw, does above code suit your purpose?